# Who were Cathy Brown and Sabrina Allen (independent candidates in 2000 US presidential election)?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, independent-politicians

[Select 2000 from results and then click more](https://uselectionatlas.org/RESULTS/)

Brown and Allen got 1,606 votes. They had ballot access in a single state - Tennessee.

For context, the Prohibition party got 208 - a fringe but well-known party - and they were on the ballot in several states.

What was Brown and Allen's programme?

This would be answered by their public statements, interviews with the media, and so on. In other words I'm not asking for 'speculation' as suggested by the close votes, but public sources. Someone who got 1606 votes - in a single state - did not manage that by getting their family and friends to vote for them. Some kind of campaigning or media coverage would have been necessary for people to even know who she was.

I missed the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathy_Gordon_Brown) as I didn't know Brown's middle name. It notes that she didn't make a statement of candidacy with the FEC, so no clues there. Just that she wanted to be the first female President - not what she wanted to change. Granted she had little chance of winning, but then neither do any fringe candidates - that does not stop them having a programme.

[Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22cathy%7Ccatherine%20gordon%20brown%22&btnG=) gives nothing relevant, nor does [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/action/doBasicSearch?Query=%22cathy%20gordon%20brown%22%20OR%20%22catherine%20gordon%20brown%22). [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cathy%7Ccatherine%20gordon%20brown%22&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1999,bkv:p&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNt5v17eT7AhX0QUEAHbUHC9IQpwV6BAgBEBU&biw=1280&bih=595&dpr=1.5) gives nothing relevant other than the book quoted in the article. This cites an interview with ABC news in 2000. I found the [ABC news transcript](https://advance.lexis.com/document/?pdmfid=1519360&crid=25022deb-e547-4412-a31a-1548878d06a1&pddocfullpath=%2Fshared%2Fdocument%2Fnews%2Furn%3AcontentItem%3A41KT-B3F0-00SX-X1BY-00000-00&pdcontentcomponentid=8277&pdteaserkey=sr5&pditab=allpods&ecomp=zbzyk&earg=sr5&prid=180cf37f-3955-454b-ad1b-282252ef8487) which mentions her:

> With Election Day tomorrow, most of the attention, of course, will be going to Al Gore and George W. Bush. Oh, there will be some mention
> of the third party candidates, too: Ralph Nader and Pat Buchanan. But
> this story is not about any of them. Instead, it's about the 12 other
> people running for president of the United States; candidates who you
> probably have never heard of.
>
> ...
> Mr. DAVID McREYNOLDS: And if you're a Socialist, vote for me.
>
> Mr. RANDALL VENSON: You have a voice, use it.
>
> **Ms. CATHY GORDON BROWN: I always wanted to be the first woman**
> **president**.
>
> Mr. HOWARD PHILLIPS: I humbly request your consideration.
>
> Mr. McREYNOLDS: If you have your head up your (deleted by station),
> vote for Bush or Gore.
>
> RITTER: (VO) And so consider this your election eve primer on the 12
> candidates who won't show up on the evening news.
>
> ...
>
> **In Al Gore's home state of Tennessee, where you need just 25
> signature to qualify as a candidate, Cathy Gordon Brown is on the
> ballot, because--well, just because.**

This segment was intended as a bit of light entertainment, not a serious look at minor nominees. Brown might well have been a trivial candidate, but as I said she must have done some campaigning to get to ~1600 votes - I'd like to know what she said.

Edit: if there is an answer to this, it's likely to be in Tennessee local news - unfortunately inaccessible to me. However I did find [a list](https://www.oldnewspaperresearch.com/blog/tennessee-online-historical-newspapers) of someone can access these resources - some of them may be available online or will be digitised in the future.

https://www.oldnewspaperresearch.com/blog/tennessee-online-historical-newspapers

Comment: [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathy_Gordon_Brown)

Comment: Ah thank you. It doesn't say what she was trying to do other than become president though

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: @NeMo - Yeah, that's why I didn't turn it into an actual answer.

Comment: Everything that I can find (which is already mentioned in the question) points to the fact that she was a vanity candidate.  Her only real policy seems to be "Woman for president", and on a ballot dominated by men that may have been enough to get a few votes from people protesting at lack of serious female candidates.

Comment: I think that's probably true, though woman for president is a much more worthy single-issue than many others I can think of. Perhaps one day a Tennessee native will come along and be able to explain it.